# PHP require folder above

Tags: php, include, directory, require

I have a file structure that looks like this (unimportant files left out):

```
Testserver
    -file.php
    PHP
        -functions.php
    Administration
        -index.php
```

Now when I try to call require_once('../PHP/functions.php'); inside the "index.php" it doesn't work and I don't understand why. Anyone an idea what the problem could be?

This works fine:

```
require_once('../file.php');
```

Comment: `require_once('PHP/functions.php');`

Comment: doesn't work (it's the index.php inside Administration)

Comment: `require_once('../../functions.php');` OR `require_once('../ PHP/functions.php');` OR `require(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'functions.php')` . Check once and tell

Comment: try require_once("../PHP/functions.php");

Comment: @Shudhansh: That is exactly what I wrote!?

Comment: @Anant tried all of them before, they don't work 
Also the path should be right since I can include "file.php" I just can't go into the PHP-folder for some reason

Comment: file permission may be the problem. change it to 644. also try once `require_once __DIR__ . "/../php/functions.php";`

Comment: file permissions are 644. I included the functions.php in a few other files and they all imported it fine. (The other files were directly in 'Testserver')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thanks for all the answers, I found the bug now:
inside the functions.php I require another file and the path to that file wasn't correct when I called it from index.php
So I had to change the path inside functions.php not inside index.php.
Still thanks to everyone for the other suggestions :)

Comment: If you employ Xdebug you can easily prevent mistakes like these :).

Comment: It may be easier to set an include path for your environment, and include everything relative to that.  I find traversing up can be problematic, because usually the include path is relative to the first called script.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you get an PHP error, and if what does it say?
- Check for lowercase/uppercase problems

The following should work correctly:

```
require_once('../PHP/functions.php');
```

Comment: The php-script simply stops working and doesn't output anything else (also no html code after it is printed)

lowercase/uppercase are correct, I triple-checked that and the file path

Still I had it exactly as you write it but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a Folder Structure Like so:

```
Testserver
    -file.php
    PHP
        -functions.php
    Administration
        -index.php
```

And then, you are inside of `index.php` trying to Access the File `functions.php`, which lives inside of the Directory `PHP`. Then you need to go up one Directory from the current directory of the `index.php` File (ie. The `Administration` Directory) [meaning that you get up to `Testserver` Folder from the`Administration` Folder] and then drill down to the `PHP` Directory. In code this would mean:

```
    <?php 
        require_once __DIR__ . "/../PHP/functions.php";
```

Hope this does it for you.

Cheers & Good Luck....

Comment: @Juliette  try var_dumping the current directory to see what you get like so: `var_dump( getcwd() );`

Answer (score 0):

Check your privileges on the folder and try:

```
require_once('../PHP/functions.php')
```

Comment: privileges are 644 and I can require it in other files so that shouldn't be the problem. That is exactly how my code looks, or am I missing a difference?

Comment: what about owner and group of the file and folder